# error importing gdata.photos.service in gae servers

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, picasa

I'm using python + django in gae python proyect.
I'm working with picasa python api, but in my computer i haven't problems with gdata.photos.service, but when i push project in GAE servers i have this error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at / 
Tried main in module trazovillena.main.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'v1_deprecated'
```

If i comment this line:

```
import gdata.photos.service
```

All work fine, buy i can't use google picasa api. I search problem in internet and people say something about **init**.py but i have all fine in project/gdata/photos and it works in anothers machines, but not in app engine.

You can see Traceback in : http://trazovillena.appspot.com/

```
 Traceback (innermost last)

 Switch to copy-and-paste view

 /base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/handlers/base.py  in get_response
             callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs =
 resolver.resolve(request.path) ... 
 ▶ Local vars
 /base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/urlresolvers.py
 in resolve
                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path) ... 
 ▶ Local
 vars
 /base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/urlresolvers.py
 in resolve
             return self.callback, args, kwargs ... 
 ▶ Local vars
 /base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/core/urlresolvers.py
 in _get_callback
             raise ViewDoesNotExist, "Tried %s in module %s. Error was:
 %s" % (func_name, mod_name, str(e)) ... 
 ▶ Local vars
```

Only difference between error or not error is include gdata-python-cliente api of google http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/ :

```
import gdata.photos.service
```

Some idea ?

A lot of thx. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Please include the whole stacktrace and all the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know what code you need, the only diference is import library. Maybe i need include somo configuration in settings.py, for example in INSTALLED_APPS, but i don't find information about it.
Thx !!!!

Comment: include the trazovillena.main.views file as well if you can

Answer (score 0):

ehm, your site is online, i presume that u are using now Django 1.x instead of the old 0.96 Django provided by appengine ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an answer to me. If it's a comment, post it as a comment.

Comment: I change GDATA API and i'm reading RSS. I'm using django 0.96.

Answer (score 0):

put gdata/src to your app root folder